# Conversion operator in C++/Cli and use it in c#( using the as operator) and use string from c++ in c#

Tags: c#, string, c++-cli, type-conversion

how to implement conversion operator in c++\cli to use this in C# using "as" operator.

This is my test method in C#:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var s = new Square(2);
    var c = new Cube(2);
    Assert.AreEqual(s.CountPerimeter(), (c as Square).CountPerimeter());
}
```

I tried to use :

```
explicit static operator Square(Cube^ cube)
{
    Square ne(cube->GetSize());
    return ne;
}
```

but it does not work.

My implementations of methods.

```
Square::Square() {}

Square::Square(double a)
{
    _size = a;
}

Square::Square(const Square% val) // copy constructor
{
    _size = 4;
}

Square::~Square() {}

double Square::CountPerimeter()
{
    return 4 * _size;
}


Cube::Cube() {}

Cube::Cube(double a)
{
    _size = a;
}

Cube::Cube(const Cube% val)
{
    _size = 4;
}

Cube::~Cube() {}

double Cube::CountPerimeter()
{
    return 12 * _size;
}
```

2)
   Also i have second problem. I want use string from c++ in c#

```
[Test method]
public void Test2()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("I'm a square.", s.Introduce());\
}
```

implementation in c++

```
#include <iostream>

string Square::Introduce()
{
    return "I'm a square.";
}
```

Comment: Please ask two different questions. It's hard to provide a single "best" answer if you ask two questions at the same time.

Comment: Don't return std::string, only a C++ compiler knows what that means.  Return System::String^ instead.  And post repro code that an SO user can copy/paste to diagnose your problem.  And *never* document "it does not work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please ask two different questions.

Please do not say "it does not work". Does that mean a compile error? Runtime error? Skynet spontaneously evolved on your computer? Please don't make us guess.

That said...

1. `is` and `as` do not pay any attention to user-defined conversions. You'd have to do a direct cast to `Square` to make it even consider the user-defined conversion. (Source: [Eric Lippert's blog](http://ericlippert.com/2015/10/14/casts-and-type-parameters-do-not-mix/). I can't find a MSDN reference for this at the moment.)
2. Use .Net strings, always. That's `String^`, with the capital "S", and the carat. If you need to interoperate with C/C++ code that uses something else, stay with .Net strings until you need to call into C/C++, and then to the conversion there.